# AHK Virtual Machine GetPixelColor

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, autohotkey

I made a script on my computer and inside of it I uses the GetPixelColor function. After I made sure the script was working well, I transported the script to my VM and realized that the colors differ...

For example, on my pc I go to a website and do the follow code :

```
^x::
PixelGetColor, BoutonSubscribe, 236, 182
msgbox %BoutonSubscribe%  
return
```

It returns me : 0xFF08FE

I do the SAME thing on the same website on my VM and it returns me : 0xFE08FD

Is it possible that the VM doesn't have the same colors ?...

Answer (score 0):

The colors are slightly different, likely because you are not using the same
display adapter nor the same display driver.

The display adapter in VirtualBox is only a simulation of an adapter that is extremely
common and so is supported by almost all operating systems
(which is why it was chosen by VirtualBox).

Your display adapter on the host is surely much more modern, with better color
support and a much more sophisticated driver.

Because of such problems, VirtualBox has been working on GPU pass-through support,
which, as the name suggests, make available the host display adapter to the guest.
Unfortunately, that feature is still very limited.

For more information see :

- [How to use GeForce GTX 1050 in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/1291482/how-to-use-geforce-gtx-1050-in-virtualbox)
- [Ryzen GPU Passthrough Setup Guide: Fedora 26 + Windows Gaming on Linux](https://level1techs.com/article/ryzen-gpu-passthrough-setup-guide-fedora-26-windows-gaming-linux)
- [Switching GPU between Windows guest and Linux host without restarting xorg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssfvpLXK8po&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer, I'll take a look ! :D