# Ensuring VirtualBox uses correct GPU for 3D acceleration

Tags: virtualbox, acceleration

I am currently attempting to set up a Ubuntu 21.04 Virtual Machine on Virtual Box and am attempting to use the 3D acceleration and it is refusing to use the Nvidia GPU and instead uses the integrated graphics card instead.

Host Setup:

Windows 10 x64

Nvidia GTX 1660Ti

I have specified the graphics card to the *High-Performance NVIDIA Processor* in the Nvidia Control Panel for the following

```
C:\Program Files\oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe
C:\Program Files\oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
```

I have also installed VirtualBox Guest Additions and have checked using nux that 3D acceleration is working

```
Not software rendered:    yes

Not blacklisted:          yes

GLX fbconfig:             yes

GLX texture from pixmap:  yes

GL npot or rect textures: yes

GL vertex program:        yes

GL fragment program:      yes

GL vertex buffer object:  yes

GL framebuffer object:    yes

GL version is 1.4+:       yes



Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Therefore 3D acceleration is working but seems to only be using the intel one.

Comment: Personally I would simply disable integrated graphics in the BIOS/UEFI settings completely. You are on a desktop. No need for power saving integrated graphics.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't pass a PCIe card to VirtualBox from a Windows Host. It is possible from a Linux Host, or Xenserver, and even then you need to have the correct hardware in other to do so. The CPU hypervisor need to be enabled for example.

At best with a Windows host you can get more video ram(up to 128mb is I remember right)once you dealt with the VirtualBox Guest Additions

I went though this once, so I dig up some of the reading I did

[Oracle on passing PCIe](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/pcipassthrough.html)

[VirtualBox forum discussing the topic](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97874)

[SuperUser Question 1](https://superuser.com/questions/1291482/how-to-use-geforce-gtx-1050-in-virtualbox)